# How Can I determine which section shows by indicator after two objects completed actions?

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, sprite-kit

I have a wheel sprite node like below and it can rotate different speeds, directions, angles. Also I have an indicator it can rotate different features (like I cited above for wheel) After tapping a button firstly I remove UIBezierPath follow action for my indicator, at the same time remove all actions from my wheel.

Here's my question. After all things stopped. How Can I determine/handle that which color pointing by that indicator?

I couldn't create a relation indicator's zRotation and wheel's zRotation. Can I get an rotation angle from first state. But If I continue first state will change.

If someone explain this case, It would be great.

[image]

> Update for indicator returning:

```
func moveClockWise() {

    let dx = person.position.x - self.size.width / 2
    let dy = person.position.y - self.size.height / 2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2), radius: 294, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
    let follow = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 500)

    person.run(SKAction.repeatForever(follow).reversed(), withKey: "personFollow")


}
```

> **Update** indicatorAngle return these values (independent from direction)

[image]

```
 let dx = person.position.x - self.size.width / 2
 let dy = person.position.y - self.size.height / 2

 let rad = atan2(dy, dx)
 var indicatorAngle = (rad * 180 / .pi).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
```

> > **wheelAngle** returns gradually increase in positive or negative (depends on wheel's rotate direction)

```
 var wheelAngle = (wheel.zRotation * 180 / .pi).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
```

Comment: Few ways I guess, but lets say this one : a circle has 360 degrees. map each 45 degrees to a certain color. So based on circles zRotation, determine the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by *@Whirlwind*, you just need to map every angle to a color.

```
func colorName(byRotationOf wheel: SKSpriteNode) -> String {
    let degree = wheel.zRotation * 180 / .pi
    switch degree {
    case 0..<45: return "Dark Green"
    case 45..<90: return "Dark Blue"
    case 90..<135: return "Purple"
    case 135..<180: return "Bordeaux"
    case 180..<225: return "Red"
    case 225..<270: return "Orange"
    case 270..<315: return "Green"
    case 315..<360: return "Blue"
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

### Update

If the indicator moves as well, you'll need to get the delta of the wheel angle and the indicator angle.

This code should do the job

```
func colorName(by wheel: SKSpriteNode, indicatorRotation: CGFloat) -> String {
    let wheelAngle = (wheel.zRotation * 180 / .pi).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
    let indicatorAngle = (indicatorRotation * 180 / .pi).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
    let deltaAngle = indicatorAngle - wheelAngle

    let slice = Int(deltaAngle / 45)
    let colorNames = ["Dark Green", "Dark Blue", "Purple", "Bordeaux", "Red", "Orange", "Green", "Blue"]
    return colorNames[slice]
}
```

Comment: Thank you but also my indicator can return around the circle, when I stop it, wheel will stop at the same time (connected same button). How can I get also bezeir path's angle to reach the wheel's intersection the color?

Comment: I have just updated my question for bezeir path features, it can go around also without reversed() follow the path.

Comment: Does `rad` represent the rotation of the indicator?

Comment: `rad` is starting angle coming from arctangent function. I appreciate your care for questions, I will check your latest update now.

Comment: Hello again, I checked it indicatorAngle is not getting gradually increase/decrease value, so sometimes goes crash. I explained latest question update what I encountered. I think needed to be generic for both direction. Could you check it please?